# Highchart - give to series-marker other zIndex then to the series-lines

Tags: highcharts

I work in angular project and use highchart.

**The situation is:**

At my chart, I have single series, type area.

I wanted the yAxis grid line to be displayed above my series, so I give it: gridZIndex: 10.

**The problem is:**

The yAxis is displayed also above the series markers, and I want it to appear only on the series area and line, not on markers.

Any solution?

Please the the demo that I draw:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for this case using the regular API options because Z index in SVG is defined by the order the elements appear in the document. You can try to manipulate the DOM, however, this solution might not work well for all cases - like dynamic chart changes, so just keep in mind this is more like a POC then a solid fix.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8p1smf05/

```
  chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load() {
        this.seriesGroup.element.insertBefore(
          this.yAxis[0].gridGroup.element,
          this.series[0].markerGroup.element
        )
      }
    }
  },
```

API to the load event: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Thanks. I have no choice but use this solution. Please notice - I needed to wrap the logic by setTimeOut, other way this failed on undefined reference (this.yAxis[0].gridGroup and this.series[0].markerGroup)